# Can A file be committed in my name in IBM's RAD without me doing it

Tags: svn, ibm-rad

Hey I work for a company where we use IBM's RAD and files where committed in my name without me doing it can this happen outside of someone on my team stealing my user name and password. we sync up with an SVN repository with another company so that is why this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Someone knew your password and used it.